# How can i change asp.net chart control series color?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write simple chart web application with this code:

```
Series Series1 = new Series();
            Series Series2 = new Series();
            Series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            Series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

            Series1.Points.Add(30);
            Series2.Points.Add(40);
            Chart1.Series.Add(Series1);
            Chart1.Series.Add(Series2);
```

that code out put is this:
[image]

but i want show to user two columns difference and show me some thing this:
[image]

how can i write code for that purpose?thanks.

Comment: Which chart tool are you using?

Comment: @User2012384 visual studio original chart control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong you are looking for stack type graph, you need to add third series to indicate difference , try following

```
        Series Series1 = new Series();
        Series Series2 = new Series();
        Series Series3 = new Series(); 
        Series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        Series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        Series3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;

        int series1Data=30;
        int series2Data=40;
        int series3Data=series2Data-series1Data;
        series2Data=series1Data;

        Series1.Points.Add(series1Data);
        Series2.Points.Add(series2Data);
        Series3.Points.Add(series3Data);
        Chart1.Series.Add(Series1);
        Chart1.Series.Add(Series2);
        Chart1.Series.Add(Series3);
```